# PO file not translate

Tags: wordpress

I just created po and mo file with POEDIT but it's not translated .

My .po file

```
#: index.php:23
msgid "This is Eng content"
msgstr "This is UK content"
```

My index.php file

```
_e('This is Eng content','custom');
```

My function

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'custom', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup');
```

I don't know what is mistake . Thanks alot .

Comment: Where did you keep the mo file?

Comment: i keep them in languages directory

Comment: What is mo file name? Try `custom-en_GB.mo`.

Comment: my po file name is en_US.po